permissions for automatic changesets with GitHub action
I'm trying to implement automatic changesets for versioning and publishing, using their built/recommended GitHub action. There's nothing in their docs about changing the permissions for GITHUB_TOKEN; nevertheless, after trying it pretty much out of the box and getting some permission failures, I updated my version of it to the following:
name: Release

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

concurrency: ${{ github.workflow }}-${{ github.ref }}

jobs:
  release:
    name: Release
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      contents: write
      pull-requests: write
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Install Dependencies
        uses: ./.github/workflows/install

      - name: Create Release Pull Request or Publish to npm
        id: changesets
        uses: changesets/action@v1
        with:
          # release script must build and call changeset publish
          publish: pnpm release
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          NPM_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.NPM_TOKEN }}

To be honest, giving write permissions to contents and pull-requests was just a guess on my part, since I can't find it documented anywhere. But given those settings, the current permission failure is extra curious:
This did get a little farther, but is still having permission issues:
Create Release Pull Request or Publish to npm
Run changesets/action@v1
  with:
    publish: pnpm release
    setupGitUser: true
    createGithubReleases: true
  env:
    PNPM_HOME: /home/runner/setup-pnpm/node_modules/.bin
    GITHUB_TOKEN: ***
    NPM_TOKEN: ***
# ...
creating pull request
Error: HttpError: GitHub Actions is not permitted to create or approve pull requests.
Error: GitHub Actions is not permitted to create or approve pull requests.

Note, I have not enabled "Allow GitHub Actions to create and approve pull requests" on the repository, but I guess I'm not supposed to need to as that would be for all GitHub Actions?
Anyone successfully have the Automatic Changesets action working and know what permissions I have to set, and where, to make it work?

GITHUB_TOKEN is a managed secret, it is automatically generated and injected into the workflow. There is no need to create a separate token for changesets.
See https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-for-github-actions/security-guides/automatic-token-authentication#about-the-github_token-secret
also see
https://docs.github.com/en/actions/writing-workflows/choosing-what-your-workflow-does/controlling-permissions-for-github_token
